# Finding untagged elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Assuming I have some HTML with untagged content, e.g:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>text in a tag</p>
other text outside any tag
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get to the untagged element?  Even document.getElementsByTagName('*') does not contain the untagged element.

TIA

Comment: Are you asking how you can get the TextNode that is a child node of the Body element node without getting the P element node that is its sibling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in your case you can do simply

```
document.getElementById('body').lastChild
```

However in a more general case you need to loop through children and check for

```
a = document.getElementById('body').lastChild

console.log(a.nodeType) // 3
console.log(a.nodeName) // #text
```

Here is example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CqXyK/5/)

Comment: I see. Thanks. That's what I was thinking. The text node type is different so I can detect it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `.nodeType` attribute which will return an integer value depending on the type of node returned. Text nodes return a value of 3. Element nodes return a value of 1 be warned however the Text inside your `<p>` counts as its own node with a nodeType of 3.

With this in mind if your looking for textNodes that are children to your body element something along the following lines should work.

```
var nodes = document.getElementByTagName('body').childNodes
for (i=0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
 if(nodes.childNode[i].nodeType == 3)
 {
 //THIS NODE IS A TEXT NODE OF THE BODY ELEMENT
 //DO WHAT YOU NEED WITH IT
 }
}
```

[MDN nodeType documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.nodeType)