# wrap the content with <p> tag which is not wrap with <header> tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In editor, If user types the content and want to wrap the content with "p" tag which is not wrap with header tag in jquery keyup event.

For example

```
<h1>Header1</h1>
Test content Test content Test content 
<h3>Header3</h3>
<h2>Header2</h2>
New content New content New content
<br/>
<br/>
<h4>Header4</h4>
```

Resultant html:

```
<h1>Header1</h1>
<p>Test content Test content Test content </p>
<h3>Header3</h3>
<h2>Header2</h2>
<p>New content New content New content</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h4>Header4</h4>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML markup wrapped inside a `<div>` for example:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Header1</h1>
    Test content Test content Test content       
    <h3>Header3</h3>
    <h2>Header2</h2>
    New content New content New content
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h4>Header4</h4>
</div>
```

then you can use **[.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)** and **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** to achieve your task:

```
$('#content').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
}).wrap('<p />');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5RBTQ/)**

Comment: Editor means that might be textarea. So use that instead of div.

Comment: I just add this in enter call of keypress event, in firefox browser it is working perfectly. In chrome browser, it normally works for p tag and if I give header tag follows it converts to div tag

Answer (score 1):

Try negating the `:header` selector and then using `.wrap()` to wrap the unwrapped text nodes in a paragraph tag.

```
var textNodes = $('body').not(':header,p *').contents().filter(function () {
    if(this.nodeType === 3 && this.textContent.trim() != "")
        return true;
});
textNodes.each(function () {
    if ($(this).parent().is('body')) {
        $(this).wrap('<p/>');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cz7c9/1/)

[:header](http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/)

[.wrap()](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Comment: @cookiemonster It does now. I didn't realize he was actually using text nodes when I first wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from previous post: [Finding untagged elements with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984804/finding-untagged-elements-with-javascript)

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('body').childNodes
for (i=0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
 if(nodes.childNode[i].nodeType == 3)
 {
 //THIS NODE IS A TEXT NODE OF THE BODY ELEMENT
 //DO WHAT YOU NEED WITH IT
 }
}
```

Comment: There's no `getElementByTagName` method. If you meant `getElementsByTagName`, it returns a collection that does not have a `.childNodes` property. You're also implicitly creating a global variable `i` by excluding `var`.

Comment: And now I've got to give it -1 since someone actually upvoted it.